# Using positive look-ahead pattern in java matchig

Tags: java, pattern-matching

I have a task in which I need to parse some data and migrate it to another column. And in some cases I need to replace some parts depending on conditions.

I read that java Pattern/Matcher supports look-ahead/look-behind operations(or grouping, I do not know how exactly it is called).

So for example I have such string
`100 K` and I want to convert it into `100000`

I used such pattern: `(?i)(?=[0-9]+)\s*[k]\b`

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?i)(?=[0-9]+)\\s*[k]\\b").matcher("100 K");
if(m.find()){
    System.out.println(m.start());
    return;
}
System.out.println("false");
```

As a result I always receive `false`. And I expected to see `3`. If I change pattern to `(?i)([0-9]+)\\s*[k]\\b` and use exact match(`matches`) operation then I see `true` and if I change pattern to negative look-ahead `(?i)(?![0-9]+)\\s*[k]\\b` then find() returns `true` and start() returns `3`.

The question is does I made a mistake in pattern or I use it in a wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need look ahead for this.  The way you've written it, it is looking for something followed by 0-9 (rather than 0-9 followed by k), and then wants spaces and a k, which can't happen as to match the first part, there must be numbers there - not spaces and a k immediately.

```
(?i)1(?=[0-9]+)([0-9]+)\s*[k]\b
```

or

```
(?i)([0-9]+)(?=\s*[k])\b
```

would match, but it doesn't seem to be what you need as you want to replace the " k". You could do this with capturing groups.  Your negative look-ahead attempt is actually returning the index you want but in an odd way - it's looking for something that isn't followed by a number, and is space(s) + k.  It would not actually require the numbers.

```
(?i)([0-9]+)(\s*[k])\b
```

will catch the " k" in the second group.  Then you can use:

```
m.replaceFirst(m.group(1) + "000")
```

Comment: Thanks Erin for explanation :) Looks like I understand how it works now. And also I can use `look-behind` `(?i)(?<=[0-9]+)\\s*[k]\\b` to achieve same result

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple, All you need to find is digits followed by (K or k)

> Regex: \d{1,}\s*[Kk]

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\d{1,}\\s*[Kk]").matcher("100 K");
if(m.find()){
    System.out.println(m.start());
    return;
}
System.out.println("false");
```

start() will get you the index of the first character matched

Comment: Thanks @Yati Sawhney. But this is just an example and real task more complex. Here I just use simple example to figure out where I made mistake in `look-ahead` operation

Comment: @AlekseiBulgak  Post some examples so that we can figure out a regex. Currently the only mistake i see is 'k' in regex and 'K' in data which might be a typo